# Firebase storage rules - logged-out user can open a doc if path is known

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I've got a simple firebase storage rule checking that only a logged-in user can access a doc:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
       
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if false;
    }
   
    match /{userId}/{filename} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I was surprised to find the storage url to the file can be opened even if a user if logged out and from a different browser where no user is logged in. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to download URLs that you generate with `getDownloadUrl`, then you're doing nothing wrong.  They always provide full unauathenticated access to the underlying file, bypassing all security rules.  If you need to protect the file with rules, then you should only provide the path to the file in the bucket, and make the client use the Firebase SDK to download it while signed in with Firebase Auth.

Comment: Ok, interesting, thanks. How would "only provide the path to the file in the bucket" look like? I need a url for the user to be able to open their file when logged in.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a plain URL that can be loaded into a browser. The browser doesn't know anything about Firebase Auth when loading URLs.

Comment: So what's the solution for a user to only be able to see their file when logged in?

Comment: As I said: you won't be able to do this with a URL, and you should instead follow the procedure in my answer.  There is plenty of documentation on how to use the Firebase Storage SDK for the various client platforms.  You should also note that there is no way to download a file using the web SDK (other than the download URL that doesn't work for you), only Android and iOS.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find an example for this and yes, i need both web and flutter, ideally. If you have any examples, that'd be much appreciated

Comment: Can one actually use firebase storage for allowing say a pdf file to be accessed only by the signed-in user on the web?

Comment: No, not as a direct download, to my knowledge.